# What type of weather proof house wrap to use around an exterior gas fireplace 225F minimum?

Tags: insulation, outdoor, fireplace, weather-resistant, house-wrap

## **Context**

I am installing an outdoor/indoor gas fireplace. The manufacturer recommends to use a minimum 225F weather proof material around the exterior of the fireplace within 6in of the top and 1in of the sides. There are no recommendations past the 6in on top and the 1in on sides limits.

I have typical house wrap covering the sheathing and using typical tar flashing tape around opening.

## **Questions**

1. What weather proof layer is usually used around fire place? (on top of the sheathing and below the stucco)
2. What weather proof materials resist 225F minimum temperature?

Comment: The stucco is the weather-proof material. What's behind the stucco will never see 225 degrees.

Comment: Well... It _should_ never see 225°, @isherwood. But that's why they're called "accidents" and why we have homeowner's insurance. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your input, Mr. Caveat.